# Angular mat-carousel is not showing images

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular mat-carousel for displaying images like below

here is my HTML Code

```
  <mat-carousel
  timings="250ms ease-in"
  [autoplay]="true"
  interval="5000"
  color="accent"
  maxWidth="auto"
  proportion="100"
  slides="5"
  [loop]="true"
  [hideArrows]="false"
  [hideIndicators]="false"
  [useKeyboard]="true"
  [useMouseWheel]="false"
  orientation="ltr"
>
  <mat-carousel-slide
    #matCarouselSlide
    *ngFor="let item of slides; let i = index"
    [image]="item.image"
    overlayColor="#00000040"
    [hideOverlay]="false"
  ></mat-carousel-slide>
</mat-carousel>
```

here is my typescript code

```
  slides = [
    {'image': 'https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net//Product//26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6//66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg'}, 
    {'image': 'https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net//Product//26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6//66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg'}, 
    {'image': 'https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net//Product//26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6//66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg'}, 
    {'image': 'https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net//Product//26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6//66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg'}, 
    {'image': 'https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net//Product//26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6//66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg'}
  ];
```

my carousel is working properly without any error but not showing a single image

this is how it display in browser

[image]

and this is the warnings that show in browser

[image]

Comment: what about the errrors in red ?

Comment: visiting a given image link on a browser shows access denied, I mean directly from Stackoverflow here. Have you tried with different CDN images or your own local pictures?

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude that's right. `AccessDenied` image. So, You try check image link `https://picsum.photos/id/${n}/900/500` and n = 700, 800, 807.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @LihnNguyen, let's use that

Comment: Now @CrazyCoder have you tried changing the images? did it now work? can we say the images were the problem?

Comment: so i change the paths like this
https://d36wja7aw8motb.cloudfront.net\Product\26f02c62-561c-47de-be7e-f44b8c3c88b6\66DDB9AB-8600-4037-A5F6-3BE8F04D5C6E.jpeg
but i'm experiencing still the same issue

Comment: @CrazyCoder let's read this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/